# About the implementation of rolling weighted average

Tags: dolphindb

I want to implement such a rolling weighted average: Assuming the rolling window period is 5, the weights of this 5 numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Which function should be called in dolphindb?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following example:

```py
price = 1..20
weight = 1..5
moving(wavg{,weight}, price, 5)
```

result:

[image]

Related functions for calculating the weighted average include [wavg](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/w/wavg.html), [mwavg](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/mwavg.html), and [cumwavg](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/c/cumwavg.html), which can be found in the DolphinDB official manual.